# Duplicate a JQuery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

First time poster, longtime reader.
I am working on a basic jQuery Slider. My problem is... Make a slider that uses only a small amount of jQuery and can duplicated on the same page to make another slider.

My Current Problem?  Getting the second slider to work. I just duplicated the code changed the CSS, but it D.R.Y (Don't repeat yourself).

I want to minify the code to work for two different sliders. THANKS S.O. Community!

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next"> >> </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"> << </a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

Feel free to work in your favorite Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue here is that you're using the same ID when you animate you slider.
You need  to generalize this so that you will only animate the slider that is actually targeted.

What I have changed is the following:

1. Removed the `ID` named slider and replaced it with a class. You can still use ID's for your sliders but they should not be duplicated.
2. On your click events for the buttons I provide the function that will animate the slider with the parent of the button (i.e the slider). By doing this you can in your `moveLeft/moveRight` functions make sure your only animate the active slider.

Note that you will have to do a similar solution to the autoplay function. I recommend you move the checkbox within the slider DIV.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var slideCount = $('.slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('.slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('.slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('.slider').css({width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight});
  $('.slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: -slideWidth});
  $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');

  function moveLeft(slider) {
    
    $(slider).find('ul').animate({
        left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
        var sliderUl = $(slider).find('ul');
        $(slider).find('ul li:last-child').prependTo(sliderUl);
        $(slider).find('ul').css('left', '');
    });
    
  };

  function moveRight(slider) {
    
    $(slider).find('ul').animate({
        left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
        var sliderUl = $(slider).find('ul');
        $(slider).find('ul li:first-child').appendTo(sliderUl);
        $(slider).find('ul').css('left', '');
    });
    
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
      moveLeft($(this).parent());
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
      moveRight($(this).parent());
  });
  
  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
     setInterval(function() {
         moveRight();
     }, 3000);
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
 html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next"> >> </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"> << </a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <a class="control_next"> >> </a>
  <a class="control_prev"> << </a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```